# LG washing machine start button quit working

Tags: appliances

I have an LG washing machine and the power button works fine but it’s the start button and I’ve taken it apart in the reserve of like a mesh sensor under the start button I don’t know what to do to fix it it’s driving me nuts help me please

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to understand your question; would you edit it a bit and add some more info? Thanks.

Comment: A picture or two of the switch and bits would be good...

Comment: Model number needed too.  Why do you think the problem is the start button specifically? Because the washer won’t start?  Or did you bypass it somehow?  Did you consider ordering a replacement start button?  Please edit your question rather than answer comments with comments.  Also please reread your current text, there may be a word (reserve) that is a bad auto-correction.

Comment: The fix is to replace the control panel. Keypad buttons aren't serviceable.